# Emailing XSLT Report using ant with Testng

Tags: xslt, ant

1)Build.xml (i have tried with both Zip destfile)

```
 <target name="sendMail" depends="makexsltreports">
<zip destfile="${basedir}/XSLT_Reports/output.zip" basedir="${basedir}/XSLT_Reports"/>
    <!--zip destfile="D:\drive d\Script\Invoice\XSLT_Reports\output.zip" basedir="D:\drive  d\Script\Invoice\XSLT_Reports"/ -->
<mail
tolist="xyz@abc.in"
from="abc@gmail.com"
subject="Invoice report"
mailhost="smtp.gmail.com"
mailport="465"
ssl="true"
user="abc@gmail.com"
password="xyz">
<attachments>
<fileset dir="${project.dir}/XSLT_Reports/">
<include name="**/*.zip"/>
</fileset>
</attachments>
</mail>
</target>
```

2)cmd Promt display below

```
sendMail:
 [zip] Building zip: D:\drive d\Script\Invoice\XSLT_Reports\output.zip
 [mail] Failed to send email: D:\drive d\Script\Invoice\${project.dir}\XSLT_
  Reports does not exist.
```

3) Folder structure

```
 D:\drive d\Script\Invoice\XSLT_Reports\output
```

Problem : Zip has been created as output.zip but could not able to send mail..

Any reply will be appreciable. Let me know if any additional details needed..

Comment: looks like your `${project.dir}` ant property is not resolved & hence is not able to find created zip, point to `${basedir}` instead in `fileset` & try?

Comment: Thanks, i have not noticed fileset dir comments...thanks once again